Value changes when merging Landsat bands to a multiband image using Rasterio in Python
I have two separate image bands from Landsat (L2SP) and would like to merge them into one multiband image (.tiff). I use rasterio package in Python in order to perform this task (see code below). The problem is that the values at the merged file have changed slightly compared to the original bands. At the image attached, you can see the results when I used identify tool for one pixel. The same applies for all pixels. How to fix it? The original images are compressed (compression: DEFLATE).
I have also applied merge via gdal in QGIS and the values of the merged image did not change.
import rasterio
from rasterio.merge import merge
import numpy as np
import os

path = r"F:\ilias\example_merge_bands\input"
output_path = r"F:\ilias\example_merge_bands\output\merged_img.tiff"
band_files = [os.path.join(path, i) for i in os.listdir(path)]
band_files

#['F:\\ilias\\example_merge_bands\\input\\LC08_L2SP_184032_20240505_20240513_02_T1_SR_B4.TIF',
#'F:\\ilias\\example_merge_bands\\input\\LC08_L2SP_184032_20240505_20240513_02_T1_SR_B5.TIF']

# List of single-band raster files
# band_files = ['band1.tif', 'band2.tif', 'band3.tif']  # Add your file names here

# Read each band into a list
bands = []
for band_file in band_files:
    with rasterio.open(band_file) as src:
        bands.append(src.read(1))  # Read the first band (assuming each file is single-band)

# Stack bands into a single numpy array
stacked_array = np.stack(bands, axis=0)

# Define the metadata for the output multi-band file based on one of the input files
with rasterio.open(band_files[0]) as src:
    meta = src.meta
    meta.update(count=len(band_files))  # Update the count to the number of bands

# Write the multi-band file
with rasterio.open(output_path, 'w', **meta) as dst:
    for id, band in enumerate(stacked_array, start=1):
        dst.write(band, id)


I have also attached the profile of one input file image.
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'uint16', 'nodata': 0.0, 'width': 7661, 'height': 7791, 'count': 1, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(32634), 'transform': Affine(30.0, 0.0, 506085.0,
       0.0, -30.0, 4581915.0), 'blockxsize': 256, 'blockysize': 256, 'tiled': True, 'compress': 'deflate', 'interleave': 'band'}



I can't access any Landsat data from USGS at the moment to test, the downloads have been failing for me since Friday. But I suggest you ensure all bands your merging have the same extent and transform. May not always be the case. You could try rasterio.vrt.WarpedVRT or gdal.BuildVRT

The values differed due to the presence of pyramids in the individual bands (in QGIS, right click -> properties). However, when zoomed in at a higher level, the values matched those obtained through the merge process.

